# How to select element name, not value, using XSL/XSLT?

Tags: xslt, transformation

We are using XSL to convert a XML file into a pipe-delimited format.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns:tradedata xmlns:ns="http://schemas.com/enterprise/util/extractservice/v1">
    <tradedata_item>
        <ORDER_ID>113632428</ORDER_ID>
        <CUSIP>31393FHA7</CUSIP>
        <TICKER>FHR</TICKER>
        <SEC_NAME>FHR 2527 SG</SEC_NAME>
        <ORDER_QTY>169249.6824</ORDER_QTY>
    </tradedata_item>
    <tradedata_item>
        <ORDER_ID>113632434</ORDER_ID>
        <CUSIP>31393G2C7</CUSIP>
        <TICKER>FHR</TICKER>
        <SEC_NAME>FHR 2531 ST</SEC_NAME>
        <ORDER_QTY>214673.0105</ORDER_QTY>
    </tradedata_item>
    <tradedata_item>
        <ORDER_ID>113632431</ORDER_ID>
        <CUSIP>527069AH1</CUSIP>
        <TICKER>LESL</TICKER>
        <SEC_NAME>ZZZ_LESLIE S POOLMART INC</SEC_NAME>
        <ORDER_QTY>365000.0000</ORDER_QTY>
    </tradedata_item>
</ns:tradedata>
```

We need the first line in the output to be the column headers, and everything else would be data, like this...

```
ORDER_ID|CUSIP|TICKER|SEC_NAME|ORDER_QTY
1136324289|31393FHA7|FHR|FHR 2527 SG|169249.6824
1136324304|31393G2C7|FHR|FHR 2531 ST|214673.0105
```

We've got the XSL working to get the data, but we can't get the header to output correctly. We just select the first tradedata_item element, then iterate the element name and separate them using | characters. Here is the full XSL...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl"
    version="1.0" xmlns="http://schemas.com/enterprise/util/extractservice/v1"
    xmlns:o="http://schemas.com/enterprise/util/extractservice/v1" > 

    <!--  xsl:strip-space elements="*"/-->
    <xsl:output method="text" indent="no"/>

     <xsl:template match="/tradedata/tradedata_item[1]">
    <xsl:for-each select="*">
      <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>|
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>  
  </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="tradedata/tradedata_item">
    <xsl:value-of select="ORDER_ID"/>|<xsl:value-of select="CUSIP"/>|<xsl:value-of select="TICKER"/>|<xsl:value-of select="SEC_NAME"/>|<xsl:value-of select="ORDER_QTY"/>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output we're seeing is just data, no header...

```
113632428|31393FHA7|FHR|FHR 2527 SG|169249.6824
113632430|31393G2C7|FHR|FHR 2531 ST|214673.0105
113632431|527069AH1|LESL|ZZZ_LESLIE S POOLMART INC|365000.0000
113632434|38470RAD3|GRAHAM|ZZZ_GRAHAM PACKAGING CO|595000.0000
```

Please disregard any namespace inconsistencies; I had to obfuscate the xml and xsl for legal reasons.

Comment: So what does your output look like?

Comment: So obviously your template is not matching anything.  Also, if it were at the top level (in invocation hierarchy) it would eat the first entry, so you must be calling it from somewhere else.  How are you invoking it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="text" indent="no"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:for-each select="tradedata/tradedata_item[1]/*">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat(name(), '|')"/>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output :

```
ORDER_ID|CUSIP|TICKER|SEC_NAME|ORDER_QTY|
```

It seems pretty simple to me. Maybe your error lies elsewhere.

Comment: Is there a way to omit the last pipe in the header?

Comment: `<xsl:for-each select="ns:tradedata/tradedata_item[1]/*">
  <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
  <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
 <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>`

Comment: Is it possible, in the section where I am selecting the element values, to use an array which has the element names instead of hard-coding ORDER_ID, CUSIP, etc? So, I'm saying, can I create an array in the header section for storing the element names, then use that array in the data section for selecting the values for those elements? This would be very helpful because if the source XML is updated with new elements, the XSL would be generic enough to pick up on it without any changes.

Comment: How would this array look like? Should it be an external parameter for example?

Comment: No, it can't be external...I'm creating a new question for this as I don't want to confuse folks with the OP. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code.. I only changed the first template to match:

```
 <xsl:template match="//tradedata_item[1]">
```

and it worked for me, i.e. got the header names.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl ofi"
    version="1.0" xmlns="http://schemas.com/enterprise/util/extractservice/v1"
    xmlns:ofi="http://schemas.oppen.com/enterprise/util/extractservice/v1">
 <xsl:output method="text" indent="no"/>
  <xsl:template match="tradedata_item[position()='1']">
    <xsl:for-each select="self::*">
      <xsl:for-each select="child::*[position()!='5']">
        <xsl:value-of select="local-name(self::*)"/>|
      </xsl:for-each>
      <xsl:value-of select="local-name(child::*[position()='5'])"/>
      <xsl:text>
      </xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="ORDER_ID"/>|<xsl:value-of select="CUSIP"/>|<xsl:value-of select="TICKER"/>|<xsl:value-of select="SEC_NAME"/>|<xsl:value-of select="ORDER_QTY"/>
      <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="tradedata_item[position()&gt;1]">
    <xsl:for-each select="self::*">
      <xsl:value-of select="ORDER_ID"/>|<xsl:value-of select="CUSIP"/>|<xsl:value-of select="TICKER"/>|<xsl:value-of select="SEC_NAME"/>|<xsl:value-of select="ORDER_QTY"/>
      <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```